# how to order by sum of counts of many columns?

Tags: php, laravel

i have `posts` table and related with `likes` table  ,`comments` table and `shares` table
i use

```
 `Post::withCount("likes")->orderByDesc("likes_count")->paginate($per_page);`
```

to get posts order by likes count .

```
**i need to get posts order by maxcount of(likes + comments +shares)** ?
```

ِAny Suggesstion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [orderByRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#orderbyraw) method

```
Post::withCount(['likes', 'comments', 'shares'])
    ->orderByRaw('likes_count + comments_count + shares_count DESC')
    ->paginate($per_page);
```